# Cannot save string to file with `\n` characters

Tags: python

The following code produces a file with content `test\\nstring`, but I need the file to contain `test\nstring`. I can't figure out a way to replace the `\\`symbol either.

```
s = "test\nstring"
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

How can I make sure that the file contains only `\n` instead of `\\n`?

Comment: Are you looking for the file to literally have the string "testing\nstring"? If that is the case all you have to do is escape the special "\n" with another backslash "\\n"

Answer (score 1):

use `s = "test\\nstring"`
I tried with the following code and worked.

```
s = "test\\nstring"
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(s)
```

and the `test.txt` file contains

```
    test\nstring
```

Answer (score 1):

The `raw strings` may help

```
s = r"test\nstring"
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides of escaping and raw string, you can encode it ([2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support) or [3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)) with `'string_escape'`:

```
s = "test\nstring".encode('string_escape')
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```